# Javascript adding to CSS value

Tags: javascript, css

I can't seem to figure this out anywhere! So I want to remove x percentage to the element when another element is clicked EACH time. This is what I have so far, any help?

```
var more = document.querySelector(".more");
more.onclick = function(){
  document.querySelector("#moreinfo").style.marginLeft - "-5%";
}
```

Comment: are you trying to subtract `-5%` or are you trying to assign? because your code doesn't do anything, it subtracts then it does nothing.

Comment: You need to get the current `marginLeft`, subtract 5% and then use the result as the newly assigned value - otherwise you're just setting a value of -5%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)** to obtain the style information for styles that are not set via an inline `style` attribute.

Also, depending on how you have your HTML set up, percentages may not work.

Finally, you have to get the current `margin-left`, extract the number portion of it, do math with that number and then concatenate back the unit to create a valid property value.

```js
var more = document.querySelector(".more");
more.onclick = function(){
  var currentLeftMargin = getComputedStyle(more).marginLeft;
  console.log(currentLeftMargin);
  
  // Element's style = number portion of current style, then do math, then add back on the unit
  more.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(currentLeftMargin, 10) - 5) + "px";
}
```

```css
.more { background-color:yellow; margin:50px; height:50px; text-align:center; }
```

```html
<div class="more">Click Me Over and Over</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to store the value of the marginLeft in a variable, perform your math on it, add back the percentage unit, and then apply it to the element. Ex:

```js
more.onclick = function() {
  var moreInfo = document.getElementById('moreInfo');
  var marginLeft = moreInfo && parseInt(moreInfo.style.marginLeft, 10);
  if (marginLeft) {
    moreInfo.style.marginLeft = (marginLeft - 5) + '%';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="more-info"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use getComputedStyle:

```js
    var more = document.querySelector(".more");
    more.onclick = function() {
        let moreinfo = document.querySelector("#moreinfo");
        moreinfo.style.marginLeft = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(moreinfo).marginLeft) * 0.95 + 'px';
    };
```

```html
<button class="more">click me</button>
<div id="moreinfo" style="background: pink;width:100px;margin-left: 200px">boxes</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the jQuery way:

```
$('.more').click(function(){

  // get the current margin-left value, convert to integer and store it as a variable 
  var marginLeft = parseInt($(".post-text").css('margin-left'));

  // then update the margin-left style, subtracting 5 from the current
  $("#moreinfo").css('margin-left', (marginLeft - 5) +'%')

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UltraPlugin.js function: 
`var myElement = document.GetElementById(element);
myElement.onclick = css("myElement {css code here}");`

[UltraPluginJs](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ultraplugin-js/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementById("#moreinfo").style.marginLeft - "-5%";
```

Replace this